# How to print the subsequent nth numbers of the Fibonacci series in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, fibonacci

I know that a similar question may have been asked earlier.

The output of my code is the length of the numbers plus one based on the user input:

i.e. if the user types "5", it is 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 8.

However, I am trying to print the subsequent nth numbers after the user has provided some number. It should be like this: if the user types "5", then the output should be 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ...

How should I modify my code to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter any nth number of the Fibonacci series.");

        string user_num = Console.ReadLine();

        int userNumber = int.Parse(user_num);

        int[] FibNum = new int[userNumber];

        int firstNum = 1;
        Console.Write("{0},", firstNum);

        int secondNum = 1;
        Console.Write("{0},", secondNum);

        int sumNum = 0;

        while (sumNum <= userNumber)
        {
            sumNum = (firstNum + secondNum);
            Console.Write("{0}, ", sumNum);

            firstNum = secondNum;
            secondNum = sumNum;               
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to have your `firstNum` and `sencondNum` after user input value you have to calculate the series from the begining. but however you can simply put a `if` before printing to check if the value is greater or equal to the user input then print it. otherwise just ignore it.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter any nth number of the Fibonacci series.");

    string user_num = Console.ReadLine();

    int userNumber = int.Parse(user_num);

    int[] FibNum = new int[userNumber];

    int firstNum = 1;
    int secondNum = 1;
  if(userNumber<=1){  
    Console.Write("{0},", firstNum);
    Console.Write("{0},", secondNum);
   }
    int sumNum = 0;

    while (sumNum <= userNumber)
    {
        sumNum = (firstNum + secondNum);
        if(sumNum>=userNumber)   //check to filter less values
        Console.Write("{0}, ", sumNum);

        firstNum = secondNum;
        secondNum = sumNum;               
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It still outputs "1, 1" before a number provided by the user and does not print a series of subsequent numbers.

Comment: @Luzing I edited the code. You can add just another if there. have a look at the code ;)

Comment: Now I better understand the logic, thank you. You just need to constrain the code with the conditional if-statement. Is it possible to print other subsequent numbers, not only the number after the given one?

Comment: Well change your while condition, `while (sumNum <= userNumber)` and give it a bigger bound (I don't recommand Infinite) something like: `while (sumNum <= 100000)`